# Корреляция в C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder

Доброго времени суток.
Пишу программу на с++ builder 2010.
Нужно найти коэффициэнт корреляции между двумя наборами данных.
Вопрос: есть ли какая-нибудь готовая функция/библиотека или прийдеться использовать Excel? 
Eсли выбрать вариант Excel, то какой лучше компонент использовать для соединения и работы.

P.S. варианты типа "смени язык" не предлогать, ибо курсовик уже почти написан.

Comment: можно тогда другой вопрос: а смысл экселя?, если у тебя все в плюсовой программе ? его ручками посчитать там никак? если я не забыл тер.вер, то там надобности в экселях в принципе нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формулы там простые - пара циклов и готово. Например, коэффициент корреляции Пирсона, математическая запись коего есть на [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

1. Считаем средние для двух выборок: X, Y (сложить все элементы выборки и разделить на их количество).
2. Считаем почти дисперсию Sx и Sy: суммируем квадраты отклонений (x[i] - X)^2, (y[i] - Y)^2
3. Считаем почти коварацию CovXY: суммируем произведения отклонения X и отклонения Y (x[i] - X)*(y[i] - Y)
4. Результат: rxy = CovXY / sqrt(Sx*Sy);

Из минусов - на выбросы в выборке он не очень адекватно реагирует.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я ее как раз сейчас реализую.
Если кому будет интересен готовый код пишите.